# Fetch previous lines from text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

the program I wrote is a program that filters the GUI according to the desired features. I want when I select the before line checkbox, it needs to show me the before main lines. For example, if my line is 18, then it needs to give me line 17 and line 16
because I write entry '2'.

How can I change this?

```
def search(msg, startingDate, endingDate, varBefore, afterLine):
    # clear current result
    text.delete('1.0', 'end')
    with open('OAM.log', 'r', encoding='latin1') as fp:
        for l_no, line in enumerate(fp, 1):
            if msg and msg not in line:
                # does not contain search message, skip it
                continue
            if startingDate or endingDate:
                # get the timestamp
                timestamp = parse_date(line[1:25])
                # within startingDate and endingDate ?
                if startingDate and timestamp < startingDate:
                    # before given starting date, skip it
                    continue
                if endingDate and timestamp > endingDate:
                    # after given ending date, skip it
                    continue
            beforeLoop = beforeEntryVar.get()
            for beforeLoop in range(beforeLoop):
                bfline = fp.readlines(l_no - beforeEntryVar.get())
                beforeLoop -= 1
                text.insert('end', ' \n ')
                text.insert('end', f'Before Line Number: {l_no - beforeEntryVar.get()} Log: {line}')
                text.insert('end', ' \n ')
            
            # insert the log
            text.insert('end', ' \n ')
            text.insert('end', f'Line Number: {l_no} Log: {line}')
            text.insert('end', ' \n ')
```

Gui Screenshot is below

[GUİ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QPJH.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.